# How to find all assets of a type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project a have several instanced of the class ArmourType (these are assets, scriptable objects). I'm trying to show these in a dropdown list in the inspector, and this works. However, I use

```
List<ArmourType> armourTypes = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<ArmourType>();
```

to find all these instances. This only finds the objects that are loaded into memory, so occasionally it only finds some of the required assets. This is documented, so isn't a bug, but very annoying at times.

So my question is, is there a different way of getting all these assets that does return those that aren't loaded into memory? Or perhaps is there a way to make Unity load the assets when they are looked for?

Note: I'm using Unity5 and c#.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
string[] guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets ("t:ArmourType", null);
foreach (string guid in guids) {
    Debug.Log (AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid));
}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.FindAssets.html

AssetDatabase is an Editor script. If you want to do a similar thing in-game place the relevant scripts in a Resources folder (this ensures they will be included in the build even if not linked in the scene) and use:

```
Resources.LoadAll<ArmourType>("");
```

Comment: I just found out that you can't use this in a game. Only for the editor. The alternative I found for in-game is `Resources.LoadAll<ArmourType>("")`. Seems to work ok but might be slow.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer for easier reference. Does this work even for scripts in a subfolder under Resources? I expect it wouldn't if "" just means the Resources root.

Comment: It works for subfolders yes. I even have multiple resource folders, each with subfolders, and it finds everything I tried.